# How to process a complex object?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am getting a response object through an API. How to get the value of the **bolded** ([paymentStatus:Iyzipay\Model\Payment:private]) key?

```
Iyzipay\Model\CheckoutFormAuth Object
(

    [token:Iyzipay\Model\CheckoutFormAuth:private] => 
    [callbackUrl:Iyzipay\Model\CheckoutFormAuth:private] => 
    [price:Iyzipay\Model\Payment:private] => 
    [paidPrice:Iyzipay\Model\Payment:private] => 
    [installment:Iyzipay\Model\Payment:private] => 
    [paymentId:Iyzipay\Model\Payment:private] => 
    **[paymentStatus:Iyzipay\Model\Payment:private] => SUCCESS**
    [fraudStatus:Iyzipay\Model\Payment:private] => 
    [merchantCommissionRate:Iyzipay\Model\Payment:private] => 
    [merchantCommissionRateAmount:Iyzipay\Model\Payment:private] => 
    [iyziCommissionRateAmount:Iyzipay\Model\Payment:private] => 
    [iyziCommissionFee:Iyzipay\Model\Payment:private] => 
    [cardType:Iyzipay\Model\Payment:private] => 
    [cardAssociation:Iyzipay\Model\Payment:private] => 
    [cardFamily:Iyzipay\Model\Payment:private] => 
    [cardToken:Iyzipay\Model\Payment:private] => 
    [cardUserKey:Iyzipay\Model\Payment:private] => 
    [binNumber:Iyzipay\Model\Payment:private] => 
    [basketId:Iyzipay\Model\Payment:private] => 
    [paymentItems:Iyzipay\Model\Payment:private] => 
    [status:Iyzipay\IyzipayResource:private] => failure
    [errorCode:Iyzipay\IyzipayResource:private] => 5132
    [errorMessage:Iyzipay\IyzipayResource:private] => token gÃ¶nderilmesi zorunludur
    [errorGroup:Iyzipay\IyzipayResource:private] => 
    [locale:Iyzipay\IyzipayResource:private] => tr
    [systemTime:Iyzipay\IyzipayResource:private] => 1458303873221
    [conversationId:Iyzipay\IyzipayResource:private] => 123456789
)
```

Comment: Where is the CheckoutFormAuth object declared? How does that declaration look like?

Comment: I haven't declare the object. I called a payment gateway API, and they are returning us this object at response url.

Comment: Then it's defined inside the API you downloaded from them. See Max's answer, he seems to be familiar with Iyzipay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Iyzipay\Model\CheckoutFormAuth` implements `Iyzipay\Model\Payment` objects methods you can use `getPaymentStatus()` method of the object.

However, it is easy to check [source codes](https://github.com/iyzico/iyzipay-php/blob/develop/src/Iyzipay/Model/CheckoutFormAuth.php) if any other questions arise.

Comment: It's hard because you haven't posted any code but I suggest you have something like this: `$payment = \Iyzipay\Model\PaymentAuth::retrieve($request, Sample::options());` And then you may use it as PHP object and call its methods: `$payment->getPaymentStatus())`